# Nodejs configuration on Windows VPS

Tags: node.js, windows, webserver, vps

I am pretty new to nodejs ( I need it for real-time application ) and got a windows VPS 2012 server R2 ( dedicated/static IP ).Now I like to configure to work as web server similiar to Apache. So I started with simple hello world example to see it is working (helloworld.js)

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req,res)
{
res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World');
}).listen(80,'static IP of my VPS');
console.log('running at 80 at static IP of my VPS');
```

started by "node helloworld.js"

it is working from localhost ( I can see Hello world output )

I have a free domain scdevserver.tk which is pointing to this static ip of VPS.But **I am not able to see hello world**

Earlier, I had IIS webserver installed(now I have removed it), at that time my default site was working from scdevserver.tk

Regards,
SK